# How to find who created an AWS AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-ami

I created a boto3 script

```
  1 import boto3
  2 
  3 #STATUSES = ( 'available', 'pending' )
  4 REGIONS = ('us-west-1', 'us-east-1', 'us-west-2')
  5 REGIONS_H = ('N. California', 'N. Virginia', 'Oregon')
  6 
  7 for i in range(len(REGIONS)):
  8     region = REGIONS[i]
  9     region_h = REGIONS_H[i]
 10     print()
 11     print("Images in {}".format(region_h))
 12     print("-----------------------")
 13     rds = boto3.setup_default_session(region_name=region)
 14     rds = boto3.client('rds')
 15 
 16     ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
 17     images = ec2.images.filter(Owners=['self'])
 18     for image in images:
 19         print("[{}] ( {} {} {} {} )".format(image.state, image.id, image.image_type, image.architecture, image.description, image.platform))
```

that gives me the following output (trancated for bravity):

```
Images in N. California
-----------------------
[available] ( ami-02efeb026dba996f8 machine x86_64 Base system for testing Progressive install )
[available] ( ami-046bd9fc47f29a58f machine x86_64 bb-rhel7-install-5 )
[available] ( ami-04c2959b96500208c machine x86_64 bb-ubuntu-install-3 )
```

Is there a way to add to line 19, so I could display ***who*** created the AMI?

Answer (score 2):

`image.owner_id` will return the AWS account ID of the image owner. Refer [this](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Image.owner_id) link.

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways to access AMI metadata and in this case AMI metadata are being accessed using ec2 resources so you need to refer[EC2 resources](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.images#filter)

and the call to get owner id should be `image.owner-id`